# how to put the line on the entire path?

Tags: angular, google-maps

I have a problem with Google Maps Directions Service on Angular, when I plot the route markers on the map, the standard Google Maps line connects the points, but when I change the color of the line, Google Maps only connects the last 2 points of the route...

I'm doing this:

```
const polylineOptions = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 5
});
this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ polylineOptions });
```

However, when rendering, the line is always shown only in the last 2 markers:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiLHw.png)

**EDIT**

I was able to reproduce the problem on the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leohenr95/ckv1eds5/).

the exact line that simulates this, is this:

```
directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ polylineOptions });
```

if you remove the `{ polylineOptions }` passed as a parameter, the "native" lines of the Directions Service appear in all points of the map:

```
directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```

Here the same code as jsfiddle for easy viewing (Note: the code here is in JS but I use TS):

```
function initMap(lat = -23.50115, lng = -46.7039272) {
    const polylineOptions = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor: "#FF0055",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 5
    });
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ polylineOptions });

    const myLatLng = { lat, lng };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        gestureHandling: "cooperative"
    });

    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    var localizacoes = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4923897, -46.6923828),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4915239, -46.6952045),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4938361, -46.6971571),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4937895, -46.6986547),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4947931, -46.7006503),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4958164, -46.7023884),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4967609, -46.7038260),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4981581, -46.7038260),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4991814, -46.7038690)
    ];

    const partida = localizacoes[0]
    const chegada = localizacoes[localizacoes.length - 1]
    let waypoints = []
    if (localizacoes.length >= 3) {
        localizacoes.splice(0, 1)
        localizacoes.splice(localizacoes.length - 1, 1)
        localizacoes.forEach(loc => {
            const point = { location: loc, stopover: true }
            waypoints.push(point)
        });
    }
    if (partida && chegada)
        enviarRotaParaMapa(partida, chegada, waypoints);
}

function enviarRotaParaMapa(origin, destination, waypoints) {
    const request = {
        origin,
        waypoints,
        destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    };

    const self = this
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            self.directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the path of the polyline coming from?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I managed to find something very similar to my problem and adapted it to my use

In this part of the code, I added another function to "map" the route

```
directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        self.directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        self.renderDirectionsPolylines(result); // HERE
    }
});
```

and the function:

```
function renderDirectionsPolylines(response) {
    const legs = response.routes[0].legs;
    for (let i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
        const steps = legs[i].steps;
        for (let j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
            const nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            const stepPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineOptions);
            for (let k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                stepPolyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            }
            stepPolyline.setMap(map);
        }
    }
}
```

and I have to add the tag `suppressPolylines: true` here:

```
directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 
suppressPolylines: true,
polylineOptions });
```

Font: http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/13ejecxj